# Comparison view of two entities in symfony/sonata admin with doctrine

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, sonata-admin

I have two entities: ServerA and ServerB, both have a field "ip address" with that they are linked to each other. Now i want to create a comparison view, where i show ServerA and ServerB in a table. Left column all ServerA regardless if they matched a Server B and right column all ServerB regardless if they match a serverA. If one is not linked (orphaned) it should be marked somehow in this view.

My first thought: A classical SQL full join use case (show left and right table, regardless if they match the criteria) ... but i read everywhere, thats not possible with doctrine.

So, how can i achieve my comparison view?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is, that doctrine don't support to get all datasets (ServerA/ServerB) which have no assignment to each other. So  i cant create a sonata admin list view where i can see all entities in one list view

Comment: In sql i would write an full join expression and it will output a table view with all datasets whether if they have a assigned dataset from the other table or not ... but with doctrine this behaviour is obviously not possible